# Need help - how to ignore specific dates for my strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm looking for a solution for my strategy.

I want to exclude trades that took place on specific dates.

E.g. I do not want to trade on days where extrem news appear (e.g. CPI, Nonfarm Payroll). So is there a way that I can say:

No trades on (e.g.) 03.02.2023, XX.XX.XXXX, etc.

And the other way -  can I somehow say, do only trade on specific dates? e.g. 03.02.2023?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check specific dates with the built-in variables `year`, `month` and `dayofmonth`.

Use these three to figure out if it is a day that you want to trade. Add this to your entry condition with a `not` operator.

```
no_trade_day_1 = (year == 2023) and (month == 2) and (dayofmonth == 3)  // 03.02.2023
trade_cond = (your_trade_cond) and not no_trade_day_1  // Trade if you have a valid signal and if it is NOT 03.02.2023
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible to just say "do not trade on first Friday of the month"? How would I code that?

Comment: Sure. You can use the `dayofweek` built-in variable to check if it is Friday. You should implement special handling to figure out if it is the first Friday.

Comment: Thanks! that helped and I already marked your answer. Can I ask you something else?
I'm looking for a turn that filter on and off function to check, how my equity curve does change. Therefore I wanted to create something like that
FilterNewsTrading = input.bool(defval=false,title='Filter Newstrading')
How can I use that in combination with the solution above? If the Checkbos is TRUE, the dates should be excluded.

Comment: Please ask a new question for that. Ideally, there should be one question per post.

Comment: Alright, did it :) Thanks for the clarification